# Removing Elastic Load Balancing results in DNS errors

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a live iOS app that uses Amazon Web Services (AWS). I have successfully set up the Token Vending Machine (TVM) according to Amazon's instructions and the app works with AWS flawlessly.

Following the AWS instructions to set up the TVM requires you to create a new environment in Elastic Beanstalk, which automatically creates a Load Balancer for you.

My Free Tier has recently expired and now I am starting to be charged for Load Balancer time. As my app is rather niche and has only a small following, I don't believe I need the Load Balancer anymore and so would like to delete it.

The issue is that if I do so (following Amazon's instructions [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah/getting-started-cleanup-elb.html)), my Token Vending Machine is no longer reachable. Chrome reports that the URL is unavailable.

Does anyone have any tips for removing ELB, when running Amazon's TVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apptuarytvmv5.elasticbeanstalk.com DNS you were using is tied specifically to the ELB associated with your beanstalk environment. If you are no longer using the ELB, you will have to access the individual EC2 instance running the TVM application.

You may want to avoid posting direct links to your TVM in the future as it does allow people to access a portion of your AWS account.

Comment: Thanks - pointed me in the right direction. I can delete the Load Balancer, change the Security Group forwarding and access the EC2 instance using the environment's Public DNS. Then using a cname on my domain I can point to this.